# Eclipse CDT "open declaration" lists the same file" twice

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), C and C++, although this problem relates to C code. Running Eclipse on Win XP.

I'm using a system with 2 projects. The projects are linked by Properties - Project References.

Some references work OK: I can use "open declaration" on a symbol in one project and it immediately jumps to the correct place in the 2nd project where it is defined.
However, occasionally I find a symbol which brings up a dialog box "Open Declaration" listing 2 alternatives, both of which are exactly the same file (by exactly the same path). One of these choices gives the correct result, the other one gives almost the same except that it's a few lines out.
Also, Eclipse (parser) thinks there are some syntax errors where there aren't any.
I've rebuilt the index on both projects, tried referencing both projects to each other and also one way only. I've stopped Eclipse and restarted it.

Any solutions?

Comment: I have the same issue, unresolved as yet.  Subscribing.  
Can't resolve specific enums in a .h file; apparently they occur in 2 places, 1 in the physical filesystem path, and 2 in the logical project path.
Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the index was out of sync.

From the top level in the project in Project Explorer, right-click and select Index-Rebuild.

Apparently it just happens every now and then; a colleague of mine encounters it regularly (Linux build).

See info about the indexer on [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_indexer.htm?cp=10_2_9_0/).

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I am using eclipse mars 2. I linked some libraries with my projects (add folder->link the folder), and when I tried to open the declaration which is in the liabraries, it always asked me choose between two files, one is with the exact file location, the other one's path is based on my project. When I open them, they appeared to be two files, which scared me a bit!

Comment: It gets worse. In a recent Eclipse workspace that has 2 projects sharing common files, often it will open the same file from each of the 2 projects; and they can get in a conflicted state and overwrite changes. THAT can be scary.  The trick is to stop and read the popups that warn of conflicted files, and be careful which response you choose!

Comment: Six years later, still an issue and still the correct solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would have to delete my project and create it again from scratch.  I didn't find this answer on the first couple of searches!  It seems to have been caused by copying a file from one project to another, although the duplicate was not in the other project, it was the very same file, just listed as the file system path rather than the /Project path.  So, make that eight years later ;)